# Maneira correta de atualizar uma propriedade de um Objeto

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

Criei um método atualizar, porem estou tendo que criar uma variável para poder atualizar minha propriedade cargo, que apesar de estar funcionando, eu acho que essa não seria a forma correta de tratar um objeto.

sendo que tenho essa propriedade no objeto FuncionarioModel segue abaixo o código.

```
public void atualizar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {
    String cargo = funcionarioModel.getCargo();
    funcionarioModel = this.funcionarioRepository.porId(funcionarioModel.getCodigo());
    funcionarioModel.setCargo(cargo);
    if (cargo.isEmpty()) {
        throw new NegocioException("Não é possível fazer a Alteração campo cargo está vazio !");

    }
}
```

caso alguém saiba como posso consertar isso.

Comment: pode ser um pouco mais explicito em relação ao que quer? Não estou a perceber se pretende reescrever esse método ou se não....

Comment: Valeu Vitor pelo retorno, eu gostaria de não ter que criar exatamente essa linha no código  String cargo = funcionarioModel.getCargo();  como estou trabalhado orientado a objeto achei que bastaria usar = String cargo =funcionarioModel.setCargo(cargo); e bastaria mais ai ele não atualiza. é isso, se eu não criar String cargo = funcionarioModel.getCargo(); para guarda o que vem no formulário, ele pega nessa linha funcionarioModel.setCargo(cargo); o que está no banco de dados   ou seja não atualiza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer eliminar a linha `"String cargo = funcionarioModel.getCargo();"` você pode fazer assim:

```
public void atualizar(FuncionarioModel funcionarioModel) throws NegocioException {  
    if (funcionarioModel.getCargo().isEmpty()) {
        throw new NegocioException("Não é possível fazer a Alteração campo cargo está vazio !");
    }  
    this.funcionarioRepository.porId(funcionarioModel.getCodigo()).setCargo(funcionarioModel.getCargo());
}
```

Observe que você deve verificar se vai lançar uma Exception antes de fazer a alteração, pois se você lançá-la após fazer a alteração o seu `"this.funcionarioRepository"` ficará com um Cargo inválido (vazio) mesmo após a Exception ter sido lançada.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Douglas, já estava sem esperança de alguém responder fico grato vou testar o código aqui.

Comment: Testei o código aqui, na mosca é isso mesmo, agora sim essa é a maneira correta de se tratar um Objeto. Valeu novamente Douglas

Comment: Se esta resposta solucionou o problema, por favor marque-a como "aceita",  ok?

Comment: como eu marco ?